# Flex realtime polyfill

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, real-time

I'm developing a service in flex which requires realtime invalidations and I was wondering which is the recommended method to add realtime support to Flex applications (any change to data models should be reflected to all subscribed clients).

Here are some concerns:

- My server is written in python3 (tornado, sqlalchemy, redis) although I don't care adding another service written in other language as long at it is simple and not a resource hog (no java please :)). My client is written in Flex and this must be supported
- I want to have multiple servers\processes to handle realtime
  connections and I don't want to use sticky sessions (SPOF?). All of the processes will be behind a Load Balancer.
- I don't
  care about the transport method as long as it is not proprietary (no RTMP), it has fallbacks and it is well supported (mostly IE9 and above)

Currently, I use [Tornadio2](https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio2) and [FlashSocket.IO](https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO) but both are not maintained and not recommended.
I thought about using [SockJS](https://github.com/mrjoes/sockjs-tornado) though It doesn't have Flex support (can I use it through the browser?), and it seems that beside FlashSocket.IO, there are no other libraries available. It should also be noted that this library doesn't have fallback capabilities.

During my research, I saw several relevant questions:

[Real-Time communication between PHP and Flex application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224153/real-time-communication-between-php-and-flex-application?rq=1)

[Realtime update and Push Data in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049018/realtime-update-and-push-data-in-as3?rq=1)

But they are 4 years old, and doesn't provide a good answer.

Any thoughts on the subject would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this topic is not hot (to say the least), but in case someone is interested, I managed to get around it by using SockJS on the flex html wrapper and communicating with it using external interface

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar in Flex by using WebSockets (sockets.io) on the serverside.  On the client side, I am using the AS3WebSockets library from https://github.com/theturtle32/AS3WebSocket

Works exceedingly well!

Comment: Thanks @bigosmallm, somehow I didn't notice this option